# many machines to complete task at the same time

Tags: optaplanner

I am using the optaplanner framework in the manufacturing process of the factory, and I use it to solve the problem of task scheduling. There is a problem that I don’t understand how to do it.

a product has 10 processing procedures, some processing procedures require one equipment to complete, some procedures require two or many equipment to complete at the same time.

Use one device to complete this. Corresponding examples can be found in optaplanner's demo. Multiple devices are processed at the same time. I cannot solve this problem now. Does optaplanner support the modeling method of multiple devices at the same time? if support,please tell me this  kind of modeling code.

Answer (score 1):

In [this video on shadow variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENKHGBMDaCM) we briefly touched upon this topic.

[image]

However, your case is a bit different, as it depends on the execution mode (= processing procedure) of the task wether it needs multiple assignees, so it harder to split such tasks into multiple single-assignee tasks. It would need a thorough analysis to design a good model for this, but I am confident it would be possible.

Comment: hi,geoffrey! thanks for your answer,and can you give me some good idea? @Geoffrey De Smet

Comment: please tell me which version for examples can find this auto delay mode,thanks!

Comment: None of them feature it at this time. We've often helped customers implement one though, so it does work.